# How to make an array map iteration synchronous?

Tags: javascript, async-await

My current implementation doesn't work because the console.log for "after" is executing before the .map iteration on querySnapshop.docs has finished. In my console I see "before", "after", and then "removing..."

How do I rework this to have the correct execution order?

```
const uid = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
let pollIds = polls.map(poll => poll.payload.doc.id);

console.log("before", pollIds);

var db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection('votes').where('uid', '==', uid).get({source: 'server'}).then((querySnapshot) => {
  let totalVotes = querySnapshot.docs.length;
  let alreadyVoted = querySnapshot.docs.map(async vote => {
    vote.ref.get().then(doc => {
      let pollId = doc.data().poll
      var index = pollIds.indexOf(pollId);
      if (index > -1) {
        console.log("removing...", pollIds[index]);
        pollIds.splice(index, 1);
      }

    });
  });
  console.log("after", pollIds);
});
```

Comment: `Promise.all()` the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily rewrite your code using `async/await`. It will become easier to read, to write, to maintain, plus it will log your `after` message as wished.

```
(async () => {
    console.log('before', pollIds);

    const uid = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
    const pollIds = polls.map(poll => poll.payload.doc.id);


    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const querySnapshot = await db.collection('votes').where('uid', '==', uid).get({source: 'server'});
    const docs = querySnapshot.docs;
    const totalVotes = docs.length;

    for (const vote of docs) {
        const doc = await vote.ref.get();
        const pollId = doc.data().poll;
        const index = pollIds.indexOf(pollId);
        if (index > -1) {
            console.log('removing...', pollIds[index]);
            pollIds.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

    console.log('after', pollIds);
})();
```

I have obviously not tried the actual code, so take it as inspiration.

Comment: Thank you so much.